# I just want to know how bottle work.When I run the following code it ended in an import error:cannot import name get .pls help me

Tags: python, bottle

```
from bottle import get, post, request

#@route('/login')
@get('/login')
def login_form():
    return '''<form method="POST">
                <input name="name"     type="text" />
                <input name="password" type="password" />
              </from>'''

#@route('/login', method='POST')
@post('/login')
def login_submit():
    name     = request.forms.get('name')
    password = request.forms.get('password')
    if check_login(name, password):
        return "<p>Your login was correct</p>"
    else:
        return "<p>Login failed</p>"
```

Answer (score 5):

You've goofed up and called something else "bottle.py".

Answer (score 1):

Use the kwarg* method='POST' within your @route decorator instead of @get or @post.

Like this:

```
from bottle import route, request

@route('/login')
#@get('/login')
def login_form():
    return '''<form method="POST">
                <input name="name"     type="text" />
                <input name="password" type="password" />
              </from>'''

@route('/login', method='POST')
#@post('/login')
def login_submit():
    name     = request.forms.get('name')
    password = request.forms.get('password')
    if check_login(name, password):
        return "<p>Your login was correct</p>"
    else:
        return "<p>Login failed</p>"
```

Good luck.

Comment: pls excuse me since I am just a starter in python.How can I see the login page(The form)....

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a file named `bottle.py` within the same directory, try changing that to a new name like `index.py` or `server.py` then run the program again.

Answer (score 0):

Nice tutorial to get started with http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=3598

OR if you are looking for some class based views try https://github.com/techchunks/bottleCBV